# Has anyone tried automating build and deployment pocess through SOMA scripts?

Tags: deployment, ibm-datapower

I have tried automating this process through SOMA: copying the file from one location to another location using dp:get-file in our local directory and their I've to change the file permissions and then unzip the file and save the folder in another location but didn't achieve.

If anyone tried please help on this scenario.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly follow all your steps, can you detail them a bit more indicating what you do on DP and what on remote system?

The key to know is that SOMA dp:get-file returns your file as a base64 encoded XML element value and you have to base64 decode that to have your actual file and then work with it on your remote system.
The other way round to put the file back using SOMA you have to base64 encode it and then sent as SOMA XML element value to DP.

I don't think DP cares of any file permission attributes? Or do you have something specific in mind?

You indicate you unzip your file. Are you playing around with ZIP-format DP config export? That would not be ideal approach. Or what is your usecase?